# Which way is better in duplicating html elements through jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a form like this:

```
<form:form name="ExpenseDetails" method="Post"
    action="ExpenseDetailsForm.html">
    <table id="Parent1_Table">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table id="Item1_Table1">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Item</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="Item1" id="Item1" required /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Expense in Rs</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="ItemValue1" id="ItemValue1"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <table id="Item1_Table2">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td><button name="Edit1" id="Edit1">Edit</button></td>
                                <td><button name="Duplicate1" id="Duplicate1">Duplicate</button></td>
                                <td><button name="Trash1" id="Trash1">Trash</button></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

On clicking the `duplicate1` button, I want to create another `table` with same elements as that of `Parent1_Table` and append it.

For doing this I have 2 solutions in mind:

1) Find the table in which the clicked `duplicate button` is located,
Get all the `id` of the elements and push it a stack,
Get the whole html of the table,
Replicate the whole `table` element and append to the original after incrementing the `ids` by 1.

2) Create the same elements invariable of the `i` of the `duplicate` button clicked,
After submission, count the no: of text elements and use them.

Which of the above solutions is to easy develop?
Can anyone please help me choose one among these?
Please let me know if you need more details on the question.

Comment: Your question is not well-defined, since "easy to develop" obviously depends on the individual's expertise and experience. I would use http://api.jquery.com/clone and http://api.jquery.com/append -- and don't forget to update the IDs in between. Do you want to copy this form just once, or any number of times?

Comment: @Blazemonger I tried the clone and the append method, it is appending the elements within the `parent1_table` element. I meant the easier method, by asking that.

Comment: You did say "get the whole HTML of the table." That includes its contents. If that's not what you want, then solution (2) is probably better.

Comment: It would be easier to develop if you could find a way to not have to increment the id's (such as not using id's)

Answer (score 1):

"Best" questions are always tricky.

I would avoid using `id` values ***at all*** whenever I'm faced with controls that repeat on every row. At most the row would have an `id` (and frequently not even then), but I'd use a class on the rest of them, not least because it plays nicely with event delegation.

Comment: But without the id how would I find the element's value after submission?

Comment: @Freakyuser: `id` isn't for form submission, that's what `name` is for. Use the same `name` on every field, and what you receive will be a list of the contents of each field with that name. (The form of the list depends on your server-side tech.) It's fine to have controls with the same `name`; only `id` has to be unique. Ex.: Change `id="Item1"` to `name="Item"` and `id="ItemValue1"` to `name="ItemValue"`. When you get the form, you'll get a list of the values in the `Item` fields and another list for the `ItemValue` fields. Entries in those lists with the same index relate to one another.

Comment: You mean to say that the name can be same for different elements and we can get their values in the controller? Is it possible? I didn't know this..

Comment: @Freakyuser: Yup. It's the usual way you deal with repeated fields. Say you have three `<input type="text" name="foo">` fields in a form. When that form is submitted, all three values are sent. Again, how you access those values depends on your server-side tech, but they all support it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the input. I ll try this and let you know tomorrow.